# Multiple select query with concatinated result displayed

Tags: mysql

From table 'phone_call'

```
SELECT * FROM phone_call;

*************************** 181. row ***************************
     id: 682
user_id: 24
  start: 2013-09-03 17:59:18
    end: 2013-09-03 17:59:20
ext_num: 2008
destination: 123473654172
call_id: 5eab044f19ed41d70661c3220f1b5c65
direction: I
created_at: 2013-09-03 17:59:18
updated_at: 2013-09-03 17:59:20
 totals: 1
*************************** 182. row ***************************
     id: 683
user_id: 22
  start: 2013-09-03 17:59:18
    end: 2013-09-03 17:59:20
ext_num: 2002
destination: 123456587458
call_id: 2eb1d9ea2e1937be30f1e93878eb3efe
direction: O
created_at: 2013-09-03 17:59:18
updated_at: 2013-09-03 17:59:20
 totals: 1
182 rows in set (0.00 sec)

...more
```

From the data above, I need a query that returns:

```
 ext_num, username, calls_in, calls_out, avg_in, avg_out
```

from the data, all in one on the fly, but am struggling a little.

I can get the individual parts like so:

```
SELECT AVG(timediff(end, start)) AS avg_in FROM phone_call WHERE user_id=24 AND  direction='I';
+---------------------------+
| avg_in                    |
+---------------------------+
| 22.0810810811             |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT AVG(timediff(end, start)) AS avg_out FROM phone_call WHERE user_id=24 AND direction='O';
+---------+
| avg_out |
+---------+
|    NULL |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are no 'calls out' (direction='O') for this user (24).

And

```
SELECT ext_num, sum(totals) AS `calls_in`, u.username
FROM phone_call pc 
JOIN user u ON pc.user_id=u.id 
WHERE user_id=24 and direction='I';
+---------+----------+----------+
| ext_num | calls_in | username |
+---------+----------+----------+
|    2008 |       37 | Esi      |
+---------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And

```
SELECT sum(totals) AS `calls_out`
FROM phone_call
WHERE user_id=24 and direction='O';
+-----------+
| calls_out |
+-----------+
|      NULL |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But how on earth do I join it all together to make one string or tupele?

Edit: My table structure:

```
describe phone_call;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ext_num     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| destination | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| call_id     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| direction   | varchar(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| totals      | int(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit: @Mahmoud
Running:

```
SELECT 
u.ext_num,
u.username,
AVG(CASE WHEN pc.direction = 'I' THEN timediff(pc.end, pc.start))  ELSE 0 END)AS avg_in,
AVG(CASE WHEN pc.direction = 'O' THEN timediff(pc.end, pc.start))  ELSE 0 END)AS avg_out,
sum(CASE WHEN pc.direction = 'I' THEN totals ELSE 0 END) AS `calls_in`, 
sum(CASE WHEN pc.direction = 'O' THEN totals ELSE 0 END) AS `calls_out`
FROM phone_call AS pc
JOIN user u ON pc.user_id=u.id 
WHERE u.user_id=24 
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.ext_num;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  ELSE 0 END)AS avg_in,
AVG(CASE WHEN pc.direction = 'O' THEN timediff(pc.end' at line 4
```

Comment: sounds like you need COUNT() and GROUP BY I can suggest something like `SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS calls_in FROM phone_call GROUP BY ext_num`

Comment: can u show the table strucutre please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `CASE` expression to do this in one query, and use the condition `WHEN pc.direction = 'I'` and `when pc.direction = 'O'` for each column:

```
SELECT 
  u.ext_num,
  u.username,
  AVG(CASE WHEN pc.direction = 'I' THEN timediff(pc.end, pc.start) END)AS avg_in,
  AVG(CASE WHEN pc.direction = 'O' THEN timediff(pc.end, pc.start) END)AS avg_out,
  sum(CASE WHEN pc.direction = 'I' THEN totals ELSE 0 END) AS `calls_in`, 
  sum(CASE WHEN pc.direction = 'O' THEN totals ELSE 0 END) AS `calls_out`
FROM phone_call AS pc
JOIN user u ON pc.user_id=u.id 
WHERE u.user_id=24 
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.ext_num;
```

Comment: can you please verify my attempt, just for sake of checking. Will be thankful to you

Comment: @Mahmoud, that looks pretty good logic-wise, upon running it though it throws a syntax error. Any ideas?

Comment: @AndrewCookson Please update your question and show my the exact query you tried and the error you got. Thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewCookson - Sorry there is an extra `)` in the `timediff(pc.end, pc.start))` in my query, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you!

```
 SELECT ext_num,  AVG(timediff(pc.end, pc.start)) as `avg_in`, NULL as `avg_out` , sum(totals) AS `calls_in`, NULL as `calls_out`, u.username
FROM phone_call pc JOIN user u ON pc.user_id=u.id 
WHERE user_id=24 and direction='I'
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.ext_num

UNION

SELECT ext_num, NULL as `avg_in`, AVG(timediff(pc.end, pc.start)) as `avg_out`, NULL AS `calls_in`, sum(totals) as `calls_out`, u.username
FROM phone_call pc 
JOIN user u ON pc.user_id=u.id 
WHERE user_id=24 and direction='O'
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.ext_num
```

Comment: @Andrew Cookson please try this!

Comment: This will give you the `avg_in` in one set wit the `avg_out` with null, and the other set will have `avg_in` null and the `avg_out` values, how you can get them in only one set, not divided into one set?